# Enviar un fichero por POST utlizando la librería Ion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http-post

Estoy intentando mandar un documento pdf haciendo una petición por POST utilizando la librería [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) con el fin de imprimirlo utilizando una impresora a la que accedo desde la nube con `https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit`

Según la documentación de Ion se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
Ion.with(getContext())
   .load("https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo")
   .uploadProgressBar(uploadProgressBar)
   .setMultipartParameter("goop", "noop")
   .setMultipartFile("archive", "application/zip", new File("/sdcard/filename.zip"))
   .asJsonObject()
   .setCallback(...)
```

Tengo una función a la que le paso el id de la impresora de google print, el token de conexión y la ruta donde se encuentra el pdf:

```
private void printPdf(String pdfPath, String printerId, String token) {
    String url = "https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit";
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("POST", url)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .setMultipartParameter("printerid", printerId)
            .setMultipartParameter("title", "print test")
            .setMultipartParameter("ticket", getTicket())
            .setMultipartFile("content", "application/pdf", new File(pdfPath))
            .asString()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "PRINT CODE: " + result.getHeaders().code() +
                                ", RESPONSE: " + result.getResult());
                        Json j = Json.read(result.getResult());
                        if (j.at("success").asBoolean()) {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomPrintActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomPrintActivity.this, "ERROR SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CustomPrintActivity.this, "ERROR NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

El PDF de prueba que quiero mandar se encuentra en el directorio downloads de mi dispositivo, la llamada a la fucnión la hago tal que así:

```
printPdf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/test.pdf",printer_id,token);
```

Al llamar a la función de este modo siempre me salta una `FileNotFoundException`, me he asegurado de que ese PDF efectivamente se encuentra en el directorio downloads del dispositivo.

¿Por qué no lo encuentra? ¿El path para el directorio de descargas no sería `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`?